# Why Ganga-snan(bath in Ganga) remove all sin that you have done?

Tags: belief, karma, ganga

I know that there is very well known ritual called Ganga-snan in north-east Indian states and Bangladesh. It is said that If you bath in river Ganga, then all sin that you have done, are removed. But why? Because all human must suffer his *karmaphala* according to his/her *karma*. No one are above from this. And also in astrology, no one can change his destiny/bhagya. Then why this ritual is so well known? Why?

Comment: There's no contradiction with "no one can change destiny"-- Because not everyone knows that Ganga bath is sin cleansing.. and not everyone baths in it.. So, whoever is **destined** to cleanse his sins by bathing in it will **only** bath, others won't.. Now Karmaphala-- Then scriptures say people who are born in India are lucky..because it has so many holy rivers, holy places of pilgrims..etc.. So, people who have done good Karmas in their past lives will have the privilege to be born in India.. even more good Karmas will ensure birth in places where Ganga flows.. So..

Comment: @Rickross  Yeah! I think you are right.